# Sum neighborhood of every matrix element efficiently

Tags: c++, performance, boost, boost-multi-array

I programmed a piece of code where I have a huge 3D matrix in C++ using boost::multi_array.

For every matrix element I want to sum up the neighborhood in a certain distance dist. Every element is weighted according to its distance to the center. The center element should not be included in the sum.

The distance dist is given by the user and can vary. My program is doing the right calculations but is slow when the matrix gets big. I have sometimes matrices with more than 100000 elements...

So my question is: Is there any way to make this computation faster? Maybe also by using another library?

The part consists mainly of two functions. In the first function I access every matrix element and calculate the sum of the neighborhood. The inputMatrix is a 3D boost multi array:

```
boost::multi_array<float, 3> inputMatrix = imageMatrix;
T actualElement;
int posActualElement;
for (int depth = 0; depth<inputMatrix.shape()[2]; depth++) {
    for (int row = 0; row<inputMatrix.shape()[0]; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col<inputMatrix.shape()[1]; col++) {

            indexOfElement[0] = row;
            indexOfElement[1] = col;
            indexOfElement[2] = depth;
            //get actual Element if it is the centre of a whole neighborhood
            actualElement = inputMatrix[row][col][depth];
            if (!std::isnan(actualElement)) {
                //get the sum of the actual neighborhood
                sumOfActualNeighborhood = getNeighborhood3D(inputMatrix, indexOfElement);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The function neighborhood3D looks as follows:

```
template <class T, size_t R>
T NGTDMFeatures3D<T, R>::getNeighborhood3D(boost::multi_array<T, R> inputMatrix, int *indexOfElement) {
    std::vector<T> neighborhood;
    T actElement;
    float weight;
    for (int k = -dist; k<dist + 1; k++) {
        for (int i = -dist; i<dist + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -dist; j<dist + 1; j++) {

                if (i != 0 || j != 0 || k != 0) {
                    if (indexOfElement[0] + i>-1 && indexOfElement[0] + i<inputMatrix.shape()[0] && indexOfElement[1] + j>-1 && indexOfElement[1] + j<inputMatrix.shape()[1] && indexOfElement[2] + k>-1 && indexOfElement[2] + k<inputMatrix.shape()[2]) {
                        actElement = inputMatrix[indexOfElement[0] + i][indexOfElement[1] + j][indexOfElement[2] + k];
                        if (!std::isnan(actElement)) {
                            weight = calculateWeight3D(i, j, k, normNGTDM, actualSpacing);
                            neighborhood.push_back(weight*actElement);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    T sum = accumulate(neighborhood.begin(), neighborhood.end(), 0);
    sum = sum / neighborhood.size();
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] rather than just a "piece of code".   A key to working out how to optimise your code will be understanding how elements of `indexOfElement` are set up and on the working of the member function of `inputMatrix` named `shape()` that is being called repeatedly.    (e.g. is it possible to do the innermost calculation in some more efficient way, based on that understanding?)  Beyond that, look at hoisting repetitive calculations from the inner loop, so they are only performed in an outer loop (or even outside the loops entirely).

Comment: Why do you need the accumulating vector? Just keep the running sum instead of `neighborhood.push_back(...)`. At any rate, google *fast matrix convolution*, it's a huge subject.

Comment: Most likely the reason for the slow code is the `push_back` (without a `reserve`). These (linear) operations are very efficient to with this Fast Fourier Transform (see FFTW library). If you do it brute force the strided memory layout doesn't help (because there will be neighbor cells that are far away in memory), so you need to switch to other layouts, such as zig-zag or Hilbert-covering (none of which are implemented in Boost.MA).